# Android app crashes because index out of bounds - even though list exists

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Basically I have a filter function whereby a user can select from a dropdown spinner and upon selecting the recycler view refreshes.

However, my app crashes even though the ArrayList exists. This is my code...

```
System.out.println("Original list size: " + list.size());
System.out.println("Duplicate list size: " + dupList.size());
// BOTH PRINT 7, AS dupList is a copy of list

for(int i=0; i<dupList.size();){
    if(!dupList.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
        //CRASHES HERE
        list.remove(i);
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

The app crashes with the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                     at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
                                                     at benzo.ShowAllGUI.filterUsers(ShowAllGUI.java:150)
```

Comment: what size log print?? List is array or ArrayList ??

Comment: Im not with you???

Comment: post your complete code here

Comment: please put i++ in the for loop and remove it from else condition.

Comment: But both lists print the same size. Surely that must mean the list exists, right. I'm sorry but the error is there - no where else in the code

Comment: for(int i=0; i<dupList.size(); i++){
            if(!dupList.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
                
                list.remove(i);
            }
            
        } use this you have to write for loop completely

Comment: yes , it's happen because your code like loops, don't remove your list within for loop.remove instead of use other arraylist store the index

Comment: lets say i = 0; and your if condition is true, then that item is removed from your list. Again i is not incremented and when your if condition becomes true, it tries to remove the same element from the list (_because still i = 0_), but it doesn't exist there anymore. Then app crashes. I think that is the problem

Comment: So the real question is how to remove all elements of ``list`` that do not equal the variable ``name``?

Comment: Are you sure your list is empty? Because even if it isn't, once you get rid of this crash, you'll run into a `ConcurentModificationException` one because you're removing items from a list while iterating thru it; you need to iterate it using it's iterator.

Comment: You have not added `i++` to the for loop.

Comment: @Shark But he is looping through `dupList` list and removing from another list. I don't understand how will it throw`ConcurrentModificationException`?

Comment: @Boss I misread that it was removing from the same list, my mistake.

Comment: @Shark Ok, can you please remove the down vote from Gaurav's answer then?

Comment: @Boss no, as it a blatant copy-paste of the codepiece from the opening post, with the increment moved out of the else-branch, thus potentially completely changing the intention of the codepiece. Rather than policing me like this, please edit his answer to actually answer the question... which I still suspect will run into the `ConcurentModificationException` due to `dupList` not being a `deep-copy` of `list`, but rather a plain reference. But without the OP showing us *exactly what `list` and `dupList` are* my concern is a moot point. And Gaurav's answer still doesn't look like an answer to me

Comment: @Shark Ok. Now with your new comment on his answer, the downvote is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you start with a copy of an original list, iterate over it and then remove elements from the *original* list if they dont equal some `name`. Do you even need the `dupList`?

Try to start with an empty list and only add those elements you want:

```
List<SomeObject> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
  if(list.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
    resultList.add(list.get(i));
  }
}
```

`resultList` now only contains the values you want, based on the same filter.

Comment: But then what about adding it to the `RecyclerView` adapter? Because I am passing the original list to the adapter

Answer (score -3):

change to this

```
for(int i=0; i<dupList.size();){
    if(!dupList.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
        //CRASHES HERE
        list.remove(i);
    }
    else {

    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11669110)